# Month ago from a date given a date in bash or perl

Tags: perl, bash, date

I will be reading random dates from a files, I want to substract 4 months from that date.  I am programming in Perl but I can use a bash command.

If i have the 10/14/2013 i will get 06/14/2013.

Thanks a lot!

Karem

Comment: I already did on my past job with UnixDate, but i am trying to find what I did but do not get any positive results on google.

Answer (score 3):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%m/%d/%Y',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('10/14/2013');
$dt->subtract( months => 4 );
say $format->format_datetime($dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ date '+%m/%d/%Y' --date='02/14/2013 4 month ago'
10/14/2012
```

Comment: Works on a Linux system, but not on a FreeBSD system.

Comment: @SlavenRezic To be accurate, this would work with `date` that is a part of `GNU Coreutils`.

Answer (score 1):

The [CPAN module Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.41/lib/Date/Manip/Calc.pod) is perfect for this sort of thing. Date::Manip is quite powerful in that it understands business days and holidays... and can parse arbitrary date strings like "next Tuesday" or "3rd Thursday in August".

You should give it a shot; I bet you'll find it quite useful.

Here's a short example the solves your current problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Date::Manip;

my $d = new Date::Manip::Date("10/18/2013");
print $d->printf("%c"), "\n";
my $delta = new Date::Manip::Delta("4 months ago");
my $od = $d->calc($delta);
print $od->printf("%c"), "\n";
```

...and this generates the following output:

```
Fri Oct 18 00:00:00 2013
Tue Jun 18 00:00:00 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

**Beware of months that have more days in them than others!**

Here's an example where subtracting one month gives you an answer that you are probably not expecting

```
endOfMarch=$(date -d "2017-03-31")
today=$endOfMarch
echo $(date -d "$today -1 month" "+%Y-%m-%d")

2017-03-02
```

Because February only has 28 days, subtracting one month has effectively created the date `2017-02-31` which obviously doesn't exist and so has spilled over the extra days into March given you `2017-03-02`

Depending on what you are trying to solve you can reliably calculate `n` months ago, by creating a date variable set to the first day of the current month, then subtracting the months.

```
endOfMarch=$(date -d "2017-03-31")
today=$endOfMarch
firstDayOfMonth=$(date -d "$today" "+%Y-%m-01")
echo $(date -d "$firstDayOfMonth -1 month" "+%Y-%m-%d")

2017-02-01
```

So now you have the correct `Month` (i.e. February when subtracting 1 month) and you then have to figure out what `Day` to set the new date to based on your use case.

So adding/subtracting Months is not as straight forward as one might think